# How can I track the bandwidth of transfers within a Dask cluster?

Tags: dask

I would like to perform some networking benchmarks on my Dask cluster.  What is the best way to get detailed information about recent transfers?

Answer (score 0):

### Dashboard

Many people use [Dask's dashboard](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html#dashboard) for this and watch for the presence of red bars in the task stream plot.

### get_task_stream

However, if you're doing benchmarks then maybe the idea of looking at a live plot during computations isn't what you're looking for.  You can get that same information by using the [dask.distributed.get_task_stream](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.Client.get_task_stream) context manager.

```
>>> from dask.distributed import get_task_stream
>>> with get_task_stream() as ts:
...     x.compute()
>>> ts.data
[...]
```

This will include information about both computations and data transfers, so you'll have to sift through them a bit.

### transfer_logs

Also, as of the time of writing this, Dask workers maintain logs of every transfer in the `Worker.incoming_transfer_log` and `Worker.outgoing_transfer_log` attributes.  You could use the `Client.run` method to get these.

```
>>> client.run(lambda dask_worker: dask_worker.incoming_transfer_log)
{'tcp://192.168.1.191:50637': deque([]),
 'tcp://192.168.1.191:50638': deque([]),
 'tcp://192.168.1.191:50640': deque([{'start': 1558119113.3489196,
         'stop': 1558119113.4012725,
         'middle': 1558119113.375096,
         'duration': 0.0523529052734375,
         'keys': {"('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 27, 0)": 463941,
          "('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 23, 0)": 464477,
          "('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 7, 0)": 463708,
          "('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 15, 0)": 464091,
          "('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 19, 0)": 464826,
          "('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 3, 0)": 463847,
          "('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 11, 0)": 464200},
         'total': 3249090,
         'bandwidth': 62061312.22384144,
         'who': 'tcp://192.168.1.191:50642'},
        {'start': 1558119113.3484848,
         'stop': 1558119113.4085395,
         'middle': 1558119113.3785121,
         'duration': 0.060054779052734375,
         'keys': {"('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 12, 0)": 463485,
          "('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 24, 0)": 464183,
          "('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 16, 0)": 464061,
          "('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 4, 0)": 464161,
          "('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 8, 0)": 463925,
          "('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 0, 0)": 464214,
          "('dataframe-sum-chunk-5b219ece79c8315870694c0e17df68ee', 0, 20, 0)": 464070},
         'total': 3248099,
         'bandwidth': 54085604.03074382,
         'who': 'tcp://192.168.1.191:50637'},
```

This is keyed by worker, and gives the start/stop/total bytes/sender/recipient of every transfer.  This solution uses internal API though, and so could change at any time.